# List-things api using http in AWS-IoT?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, iot

I am new to this AWS IoT, i was able to get/update thing shadows using http api (https://endpoint/things/thingName/shadow), provided by AWS IoT, but i want the list of things created under my account. Documentation provides the way of getting list-things using AWS CLI, how can i achieve the same using rest-api ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, first i build up custom sdk for AWS IoT, using this [link](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) you can build, i selected AWS.IoT and AWS.IoTData and build a sdk. After importing that sdk to your solution, you can query like this :

```
var iot = new AWS.Iot({
            "accessKeyId":"accessKeyId",
            "secretAccessKey":"secretAccessKey",
            "region":"region"
            });

            iot.listThings({}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
              else     console.log(data);           // successful response
            });
```

You can find the API documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html)

Comment: Hey @Chirag, I've been trying with the same code but keep getting this: NetworkingError: Network Failure. A 403 error when hitting https://iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/things. Were you able to run this without any issues?

Comment: @hernangarcia, Yes, i was able to run this without any issue, you better check your AWS credentials and aws-iot-sdk. 403 is forbidden, so i think there's some issue with credentials only.